# Remove all '/n' from body of the HTTP request for end point to accept the POST action in Power Automate

Tags: power-automate, power-automate-custom-connector

I am building a flow that does 2 HTTP requests, one to get CSV data, and a second one to POST this CSV data.

The end point receiving the POST request is a bit sensitive and requires all the details in the Body to have/r/n instead of /n.

I had done that change to the CSV data successfully, but when I am drafting the Body in the HTTP connector and test the flow, I can see that the parameters in the body, outside the CSV data, gets send with /n as break lines.

I have tried to remove those but still I haven't been successful. Do you have any idea how can I overcome this issue?

Please see screenshot below for more information:

[image]

This is the data that gets sent to the end point, I need all the text inside the body to contain \r\n instead of \n

[image]

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I would suggest initializing a variable at the top of the flow. The Set the value of it to [that exact thing you want it to be]. And then use the varibale inside the HTTP action, similar to the compose / output that we see in the image. I am not sure how or why, but the variable values appears to be taken very literally by Power Automate. That is where I would begin.